# Choosing Python/SQLObject webframework

Tags: python, sqlobject

I have a regular desktop application which is written in Python/GTK and SQLObject as ORM. My goal is to create a webinterface where a user can login and sync/edit the database. My application is split up in different modules, so the database and gtk code are completly separate, so I would like to run the same database code on the webserver too.

So, I would like to know if there's a webframework which could handle these criteria:

- User authentication
- Use my own database code/SQLObject
- Some widgets to build a basic ui

This would be my first webproject, so I'm a bit confused by all searchresults. CherryPy, Turbogears, web2py, Pyramid? I would be happy if someone could give me some pointers what would be a good framework in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the options you name would work. Scan through their docs, and decide what looks like the nicest to you.

Flask is another lightweight option: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Django would work too (just ignore its ORM for your own work, and configure it to look at a different database within your database server, to keep it separated from your own ORM).

Answer (score 0):

Try the pyramid, it does not impose anything you like as opposed to Django. And has a wealth of features for building Web applications at any level.